# the cache in physics isnt accessible for simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation

[image] I am trying to learn smoke simulation however after selecting the object and doing quick smoke, the cache panel isn't being responsive in the physics tab for baking

Answer (score 2):

You have to save the file once first, the cache-files will be written in a folder at the same locatation as the saved blend file.